# Is either $n! + 1$ or $n! - 1$ not prime for all $n$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, factorial

I was looking at an article about factorial primes, and I noticed that both $n!+1$ and $n!-1$ were not prime. (As in, there are no numbers $n$ such that both $n!+1$ and $n!-1$ are prime). I think that for any $n$, both $n!+1$ and $n!-1$ cannot be prime. Is this an easy thing to prove? If so, how? Would Wilson's theorem be applicable in some way?

This is just a conjecture that I am asking out of curiosity. I would love some thoughts on how one might approach such a problem as this one.

Comment: How about $n=3$?

Comment: Oh... I did not notice that. However $n=3$ is the only case for which this happens.

Comment: A proof is probably not easy.  If you think about $8!$ we are asking about $40219=23\cdot 2153$ and $40321=61\cdot 661$.  In this case neither is prime, but it is not clear what relationship the factors have to $8$.

Comment: @RossMillikan:  I think you meant $40319=23\cdot1753$, but your point remains

Comment: @J.W.Tanner:  yes, I miscopied it from Alpha

Comment: Confirmed by computer for $n = 4, \ldots , 3000$.

Comment: The Wikipedia article [Factorial Prime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial_prime) links to the OEIS entries for both prime $n!+1$ and prime $n!-1$.  The number of these known is fairly small, of either kind.

Comment: @David G. Stork You must have some sort of monster computer. I plugged in the range $[4,50]$ into my desktop and it's struggling. Or perhaps it's my proficiency for writing horribly inefficient python code.

Comment: @David G. Stork Wow. How did you check efficiently the primality of such huge numbers?

Comment: @K.defaoite:  There are computational tricks.  The first is parallelization (yes... even on a laptop).  The second is incrementalism... If you have $1000!$, it is a simple matter to compute $1001!$.  The third is checking just $1$ of the potential pairs to see if it is prime (so you don't have to perform the costly prime test on the partner if not necessary).  All this is pretty straightforward undergraduate computer science...  I did it all in *Mathematica*.

Comment: @K.defaoite  I write my own simple algorithms. For this one, I have something that does trial division of a big number using primes up to some bound I specify in the program. That may give  small prime factors for both $n!.$  It would be equivalent, and use fewer huge numbers, to write a program for reducing mod $p$ for a specified $p.$  For each $p,$  you can check $n!$  mod $p$ as long as $n < p,$ because  when $p \leq n$  we have $p | n!,$  whereupon $n! \pm 1$  cannot be divisible by $p$

Comment: @DavidG.Stork could you please post an answer with the smallest prime factors of $n! + 1$  and $n! - 1 \; \; ? \;$ for, say $n \leq 50 \; ? \;$

Comment: It's an open problem. If a counterexample exits, it is larger than $n\gt 208003$, at least.

Comment: @K defaoite: Note that you don’t need to show that n!-1 is composite, or that n! + 1 is composite, but that _one_ is. So just using trial division, for all primes p>n you calculate n! Modulo p and check if it is +1 or -1, and there’s a chance that one of them isn’t, with a rather small p. And then you do a Fermat Primality Test but use it as a compositeness test. Either n!-1 or n!+1 is likely to fail rather quickly. That test isn’t very good at showing primarily, but it is good at showing compositeness in most cases.

Comment: If $n!−1$ and $n!+1$ are both primes, then they are twin primes. Twin primes $6k\pm 1$ occur iff $k\ne 6ab\pm a\pm b$; see [OEIS A002822](http://oeis.org/A002822). The question posed then becomes $\forall n>3⇒\frac{n!}{6}=6ab±a±b$?

Answer (score 17):

The [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A088054) entry on factorial primes currently states that this is an open problem:

> Conjecture: 3 is the intersection of [A002981](https://oeis.org/A002981) and [A002982](https://oeis.org/A002982).

The two referenced sequences consist of the natural numbers $n$ such that $n!+1$ is prime, and the $n$ such that $n!-1$ is prime, respectively. Their intersection is exactly the numbers $n$ you are looking for, where both $n!+1$ and $n!-1$ are prime.

Answer (score 4):

The smallest prime factors of $n!^2 - 1$ for the first few values of $n$ seem to me to be bizarrely small but I only know how to "explain" some of them. Wilson's theorem gives, for a prime $p$, the following:

$$(p-1)! \equiv -1 \bmod p$$
$$(p-2)! \equiv 1 \bmod p$$
$$\left( \frac{p-1}{2} \right)! \equiv \pm 1 \bmod p, p \equiv 3 \bmod 4$$

(the last one is a nice exercise). More generally we have

$$(p-k)! \equiv (-1)^k (k-1)! \bmod p$$

which will explain one mystery a bit later. Now, applying the first three facts, we have

$$3! \equiv 1 \bmod 5, -1 \bmod 7$$
$$4! \equiv -1 \bmod 5$$
$$5! \equiv 1 \bmod 7, -1 \bmod 11$$
$$6! \equiv -1 \bmod 7$$

The first one I don't know how to explain is

$$7! \equiv -1 \bmod 71$$

but it's striking that $71 \equiv 1 \bmod 7$. Also we have

$$8! \equiv 1 \bmod 23, -1 \bmod 61$$

which I also don't know how to explain, but it's again striking that $23 \equiv -1 \bmod 8$. Then we have easy Wilson cases again,

$$9! \equiv 1 \bmod 11, -1 \bmod 19$$
$$10! \equiv -1 \bmod 11$$
$$11! \equiv 1 \bmod 13, 23$$
$$12! \equiv -1 \bmod 13$$

and then the fairly mysterious

$$13! \equiv -1 \bmod 83$$

(here we have $83 \equiv 5 \bmod 13$ which is a square root of $-1 \bmod 13$, what's up with that) and the somewhat more explainable

$$14! \equiv (23-9)! \equiv -8! \equiv -1 \bmod 23.$$

Next is a round of Wilson's theorem again:

$$15! \equiv 1 \bmod 17$$
$$16! \equiv -1 \bmod 17$$
$$17! \equiv 1 \bmod 19$$
$$18! \equiv -1 \bmod 19$$

and then

$$19! \equiv -1 \bmod 71$$

(recall that we saw above that $7! \equiv -1 \bmod 71$, and I didn't include it above but we also have $9! \equiv -1 \bmod 71$). Up until this point the smallest prime factor was at most $2$ digits which I personally think is wacky, but now I am defeated: for $n = 20$ the smallest prime factor is

$$20! \equiv 1 \bmod 124769$$

so whatever's been powering our luck it's run out. There are some other coincidences I don't know how to explain: for example, $61$ divides not only $8!+1$ but also $16!+1$ and $18!+1$, and $661$ divides not only $8!+1$ but also $17!+1$. Very strange.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a full answer, but some supporting material, explicitly requested in comments.

First, in *Mathematica* here is non-optimized code to show how to perform the posed search (for $n = 1000, \ldots 2000$) on a four-processor machine:

```
CloseKernels[]; 
LaunchKernels[4];
Parallelize[
 {t1 = 1000!;
  Do[t = t1 n;
   If[PrimeQ[t - 1], If[PrimeQ[t + 1], Print[t]]],
   {n, 1001, 1300}],
  t2 = 1300!;
  Do[t = t2 n;
   If[PrimeQ[t - 1], If[PrimeQ[t + 1], Print[t]]],
   {n, 1301, 1600}],
  t3 = 1600!;
  Do[t = t3 n;
   If[PrimeQ[t - 1], If[PrimeQ[t + 1], Print[t]]],
   {n, 1601, 1800}],
  t4 = 1800!;
  Do[t = t3 n;
   If[PrimeQ[t - 1], If[PrimeQ[t + 1], Print[t]]],
   {n, 1801, 2000}]
  }
 ]
```

In brief, there are four threads, each covering at a different range of $n$.  (You don't want equal-sized ranges of $n$s, because the large $n$s require more compute time, of course.)

Now, here's a table of $n$ and the factors of $n!-1$ and $n!+1$.

Here's the *Mathematica* code... just change $20$ to $50$ or whatever you like.

```
TableForm[
 Table[{n, FactorInteger[n! - 1], FactorInteger[n! + 1]},
  {n, 1, 20}]
 ]
```

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right) & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 2 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
 2 & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right) & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 3 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
 3 & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 5 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right) & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 7 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
 4 & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 23 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right) & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 5 & 2 \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
 5 & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 7 & 1 \\
 17 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right) & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 11 & 2 \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
 6 & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 719 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right) & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 7 & 1 \\
 103 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
 7 & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 5039 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right) & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 71 & 2 \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
 8 & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 23 & 1 \\
 1753 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right) & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 61 & 1 \\
 661 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
 9 & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 11 & 2 \\
 2999 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right) & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 19 & 1 \\
 71 & 1 \\
 269 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
 10 & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 29 & 1 \\
 125131 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right) & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 11 & 1 \\
 329891 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
 11 & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 13 & 1 \\
 17 & 1 \\
 23 & 1 \\
 7853 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right) & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 39916801 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
 12 & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 479001599 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right) & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 13 & 2 \\
 2834329 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
 13 & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1733 & 1 \\
 3593203 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right) & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 83 & 1 \\
 75024347 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
 14 & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 87178291199 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right) & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 23 & 1 \\
 3790360487 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
 15 & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 17 & 1 \\
 31 & 2 \\
 53 & 1 \\
 1510259 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right) & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 59 & 1 \\
 479 & 1 \\
 46271341 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
 16 & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 3041 & 1 \\
 6880233439 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right) & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 17 & 1 \\
 61 & 1 \\
 137 & 1 \\
 139 & 1 \\
 1059511 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
 17 & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 19 & 1 \\
 73 & 1 \\
 256443711677 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right) & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 661 & 1 \\
 537913 & 1 \\
 1000357 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
 18 & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 59 & 1 \\
 226663 & 1 \\
 478749547 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right) & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 19 & 1 \\
 23 & 1 \\
 29 & 1 \\
 61 & 1 \\
 67 & 1 \\
 123610951 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
 19 & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 653 & 1 \\
 2383907 & 1 \\
 78143369 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right) & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 71 & 1 \\
 1713311273363831 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
 20 & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 124769 & 1 \\
 19499250680671 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right) & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 20639383 & 1 \\
 117876683047 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: Very nice. I just did a small Fermat method

Comment: Note that for most composite numbers a test succeeds quickly. So a test that either x or y is composite will be faster than testing separately x is composite, or y is composite. Especially if you test x first, and x is prime.

Comment: @gnasher729 he said that in comments yesterday